# sum comma delimited string of integers

Tags: google-sheets, sum

In Google Sheets - I need to sum a set of numbers, where the initial cell contains delimiters and non numerics:

```
3; 6; 1; 3; None; 1; 1
```

I first replace all spaces and non numerics:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(AG24,"\D+",",")
```

Which gives: 3,6,1,3,1,1

Since `=SUM(3,6,1,3,1,1)` correctly provides 15, I figured I'd try passing in the `REGEXREPLACE` result into `SUM()` and magically have it compute, but doing so yields 0:

```
=SUM(REGEXREPLACE(AG24,"\D+",",")) = 0
```

I kind of expected that...

I've also tried `SUMPRODUCT`, which also yields 0:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(AG24,"\D+",","))) = 0
```

**Question:** so how can I sum the list of string integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=sum(split(REGEXREPLACE(AG24,"\D+",","),","))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below formula which will directly convert the string to array ad then make a sum of it.

```
=Sum(SPLIT(AG24,";"))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

- `=SUMPRODUCT(SPLIT(AG24, ";"))`
- `=SUMPRODUCT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(AG24,"\D+"," ")," "))`

will work as well...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are in the world, the parameters of google sheets functions are separated by different characters.

US version using comma seperation: `=Sum(SPLIT(AG24,";"))`

EU version using semicolon: `=Sum(SPLIT(AG24;";"))`

I'm located in EU but only found US documentation, so I was confused for a long time