# Google Sheets ArrayFormula Solution for Multiplying 2 Columns, One of Which Is a Column of Lists of Numbers

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas

I have 2 columns of inputs (A and B) and 1 column of output (C) with the number of rows unknown at design time. Each row’s inputs and outputs are independent; row 1 cannot affect row 2.

- Column A consists of 2 possible types: a positive integer or a list of positive integers delimited by semicolons (“`;`”).
- Column B consists of only a positive integer.
- Column C is the total of column A multiplied by column B.

This is the basic formula I have devised for column C: `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK($A2)),IF(ISNUMBER($B2),$A2*$B2,$B2*SUM(SPLIT($A2,"; ")))),"")`. And it works by filling the formula downwards, but the `SUM` being there makes it incompatible with `ARRAYFORMULA`. For robustness (because I cannot count on the users to autofill the cells themselves nor to avoid wreaking havoc on the formulae I’ve carefully laid down), I would like an `ARRAYFORMULA`-based solution which I can tuck inside of one protected cell in column C.

The current result using the non-`ARRAYFORMULA` solution:

[image: Table of example inputs and outputs]

The first 4 rows are just simple multiplication, which `ARRAYFORMULA` has no trouble doing. The last filled row represents `(15+20+25)*1=60` which I could not do as an `ARRAYFORMULA`.

I have found one similar question which—unfortunately—does not apply to my case because the final solution does not use `ARRAYFORMULA`: [sum comma delimited string of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54662379/sum-comma-delimited-string-of-integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A<>"")*(ISNUMBER(B2:B)), 
 MMULT(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, ";")*1, 0), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, ";")*1, 0))))^0)*B2:B, ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This hacky solution is *totally* functional! And the blank inputs cause the output to be blank as well (as expected). But I’m at a loss to explain *why* it works! `(A2:A<>"")*(ISNUMBER(B2:B))` checking for valid input is as far as my comprehension goes. `IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, ";")*1, 0)` is a bit cryptic as is the purpose of `ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(`.

Comment: (if a2 is not empty = TRUE) multiplied by (if B2 is number = TRUE) = TRUE because 1*1=1 (simple math logic) if 1*0 or 0*1 or 0*0 scenario happens its equal to 0 and in that case cell on that row stays empty

Comment: split A2 on each ; is obvious but if there is no ; in A2 (or A7)  then you got N/A error so you wrap split into IFERROR and if error happens then 0 is outputed. now explanation for that *1 ... A6 will output 3 columns coz of 3 values but A5 will output only 1 column so next 2 columns are empty and that is not good for MMULT which works only with numbers and empty cell will lead to error. so you multiply empty cell by *1 to get 0 eg convert blank cells into zeros

Comment: here is how simplified MMULT works: =MMULT(A1:C1, {1;1;1}) which reads: to sum values of 3 columns (horizontal array) we need to pair it with same amount of vertical array eg 3 rows of ones {1;1;1} aka TRANSPOSE({1,1,1}) aka ROW(A1:A3)^0 ...its all the same